# How to inherit postscript increment from base class and return derived class in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, post-increment

I have several c++ classes that have similar behaviours. Moreover most of the class methods can be constructed from few fundamental ones. So I want to define a base class with the derived methods, inherit from the base class and define the remaining methods in the derived classes.
This is my attempt using the CRTP

```
template <class derived_class> class base_class {
public:
    virtual derived_class& operator++ () = 0;
    virtual derived_class& fun1() = 0;
    derived_class operator++ (int) {
        derived_class toreturn(static_cast<derived_class&>(*this));
        ++*this;
        return toreturn;}
    derived_class& fun2() {
        this->fun1();
        return static_cast<derived_class&>(*this);
    };
};

class deriv1 : public base_class<deriv1> {
public:
   int n;
    deriv1():n(0){};
    deriv1(deriv1& other):n(other.n){};
    deriv1& operator++ () override { ++n; return *this;}
    deriv1& fun1() override { n *= n; return *this;}
};
```

I don't understand why fun2() works but not the postscript increment.
If I call the postscript increment on a derived object I get the error message "*Cannot increment value of type 'deriv1'*".

Comment: CRTP usually doesn't use virtual members.

Comment: Add `using base_class::operator++;` inside `deriv1`. I believe the issue is because the declaration of `operator++() override` is hiding the definitions from the base class. So you need to pull the definitions into this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a using statement:

```
class deriv1 : public base_class<deriv1> {
public:
    ....
    using base_class::operator++; 
};
```

The problem is that function resolution is failing. Lets think of a simpler solution to illustrate the problem:

```
struct Base
{
    void f()    {}
    void f(int) {}
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    void f()    {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived a;
    a.f(1);     // This fails as there is no f() that takes an integer
                // in Derived. And since the compiler found an f() in
                // Derived it stopped looking further up the chain
                // for additional matches.
}
```

This problem is solved in the same way.

```
struct Derived: public Base
{
    using Base::f;
    void f()    {}
};
```